# Remove rounded corners from text field, keep background opacity iOS Swift

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit, opacity

In Xcode 6.3, on creating a text view, there are 4 options given for the border style.

[image]

The rounded corner border style provides the option of changing the opacity of the background (not the text).

The square corner border style's alpha value only changes the opacity of the text, and not the background of the text field.

How do I have a square-cornered text field with a 0.5 Alpha value for background opacity, but a 0.0 Alpha Value for text opacity?

Comment: Use Firstone option of BoarderStyle and give background color White.

Comment: 0 opacity gives pure white, 1 opacity gives black. How do I make 0 opacity give full transparency?

Comment: You want a 0.0 alpha for your text?  Invisible text?  Are you certain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any combination you want programmatically. Eg:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    myTextField.backgroundColor = backColor

    let textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    myTextField.textColor = textColor

}
```

You could also set the background or text color to `Clear Color` in the Attributes inspector.